# Is there a front end for tor using only a browser?

Tags: client

I wonder whether there is a front end for tor using only a web browser. For example, I want to run tor in my router, and I want the computers connected to it to monitor the status of tor using only a web browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/ijcoe6ru/php_tor_controller/

This one only needs a browser. But you need to have an http server installed on the router.